# kendo - kendoscrollview image width issues

Tags: kendo-ui

I have used kendo scroll view by referring to the official website, unfortunatey in my application when I try to set the image width to ensure that I have responsiveness, I am unable to see the other image i.e consider I have 2 images if the image container width is set to 100% the carousel completely changes having only one image and not showing an option to move to the next image its as if the next image isnt being rendered itself..

https://dojo.telerik.com/iHibOzat/4